# Update to angular cli 14 brakes some ts module imports - Error: Module not found: Error: Resolving to directories is not possible (request was ./api/)

Tags: typescript, import, angular-cli

I have updated my system to angular cli V-14.2.11 and run ng serve. I get few errors like the following:

> ./src/app/../projects/run.effects.ts:22:0-35 - Error: Module not
> found: Error: Resolving to directories is not possible with the
> exports field (request was ./api/)

caused by the last import in the following code:

> import { RestService } from '../rest.service';
>
> import * as projectActions from './project.actions';
>
> import {ICase, IProject, IRun, runsUrl, importRunUrl, ICaseLogs,
> athleteRunUrl} from './projects.models';

My code is trying to access a **projects.models.ts** located in the same folder. The location is correct and vs-code does not report any error

This is driving me mad, I have tried all of the following:

1. updated **typescript** to version **~4.6.4**
2. changed to absolute path '@app/../projects/projects.models'

I do not have any idea of what else can cause this error. Thank you for any help or suggestion that can send me in the right direction to fix this

**modified**

I believe **Akxe** pointed me in the right direction.
I have an export in the ./project.models.ts defined like:

**export const athleteRunUrl = 'api/../../create_athlete_run/';**

it looks like the **run.effect.ts** cannot see it. It was working in Angular 13, what has changed in Angular 14?

Comment: Could you share your file tree structure? The relevant bits? What is `./api/`

Comment: Hi Akxe, I think you put me in the right direction I have an export in the ./project.models.ts defined like: 
export const athleteRunUrl = 'api/../../create_athlete_run/';
it looks like the run.effect.ts cannot see it. it was working in Angular 13, what is changed in Angular 14?

Comment: It will be a TS fix... probably the path should start with `/`, `./` or `../`; starting with anything else is non deterministic. Also, see if your VSCode does use npde_modules version of TS